# Cannot connect with Remote Desktop Win Server 2012 r2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop

I just got a new machine and installed Windows Server r2 on it. I enabled remote desktop and added static IP. Pinging works.

I then tried to connect to the server using Remote Desktop on the local Admin account (admin account on the server), but it says logon attempt failed.

I tried the following usernames: SERVERNAME/Administrator, Administrator, .\Administrator, many more combinations
I also tried without using any firewalls on the server and client, logged in and not logged in the admin account on the server.

Any idea how can I connect with Remote Desktop to the server? I can't find any information online.

Comment: Do you still have access to the console?  Do the same credentials work there?  If so, does the error log say anything interesting?

Comment: I checked the Event Viewer and i get some error events when I try to connect... eventID 103 (disconnect reason is 12), eventID 103 (disconnect reason is 0), eventID 102 (the server has terminated main rdp connection with client). I tried running remote desktop on the server and connecting to itself, which worked.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any Licensing issue with Windows Server 2012 R2 or Remote Desktop...Here, Remote Desktop Services Events are explained in detail...https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404144(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I made a new install of the OS, and now it seems to work flawlessly on the first try. I guess the installation got messed up. Thanks for your help!